# notation in expectation of continuous random variable question

Tags: expected-value, density-function

What does the 'x' over the '2' mean in the statement of the values this function takes[image: pdf values]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the definition. It's likely to be $\frac x 2$, because when it is, the function integrates to $1$ and therefore a valid PDF. You can then find the expected value using $$E[X]=\int_0^2x\frac{x}{2}dx$$